# JavaFx Image to byte[] array (Closed)

Tags: java, arrays, image, javafx, byte

I need a fast way to convert a JavaFX Image to an byte array.

The way with "BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(i, null);" is to slow.

I thinks its better to not convert the Image first to the awt.BufferedImage.

So what I have so far is:

```
    PixelReader pr = img.getPixelReader();

    WritablePixelFormat<ByteBuffer> pixelformat = WritablePixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance();

    int w = (int) img.getWidth();
    int h = (int) img.getHeight();
    int offset = 0;
    int scanlineStride = w * 4;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[w * h * 4];

    pr.getPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixelformat, buffer, offset, scanlineStride);
```

But this is not working as excepted.

Seems like the byte[] is empty or so?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how the behavior is different to what you expect?

Comment: I think i now where my Problem is. I am trying to display the image in a Webpage. But im doing something wrong with reading the blob.  The code I posted, is it right?

Comment: My Solution also causes a OutOfMemory after some calls.

Comment: It looks correct to me. (I've always used `int[]` representations, not `byte[]`, so I have no code to check directly against, but I see nothing wrong.)

Comment: Seems like the byte[] is empty. See Screenshot.

Comment: I tested the exact code you posted and it worked fine. https://gist.github.com/james-d/4376831966915e7af883

Comment: Okay I see the Problem. The Image was just empty while I was debugging. Thanks for your help. I will try some other stuff now.

Answer (score -3):

you can use `toByteArray()` method of `IOUtils` class from `org.apache.commons` package. [see here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)

Comment: No i cant. Because I dont have any stream or something I can use for that. If I convert to Fx-Image to an AWT-Image I can use OutputStreams to do it. But this is to slow.